# Getting Bookmarks Programmatically in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-macros

I am using VS 2010 and I want to do something quite simple.  Write a Macro / Add-in which will

- Save the bookmarks to a file (e.g. "myfile.bookmarks")
- Load bookmarks from a file.

I just cannot find any API within `DTE` (when writing a macro) nor can I find anything within the `Microsoft.VisualStudio` namespace when creating an addin.

Can someone please help?

---

(The one thing I want to avoid is re-creating bookmarks functionality, although I can use code from [Numbered Bookmarks extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61915/Numbered-Bookmarks-Visual-Studio-Extension-VSX-201)).

Comment: It is possible to enumerate all bookmarks and save positions [EditPoint.NextBookmark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.editpoint.nextbookmark.aspx)